# Compiling error

Tags: makefile

I downloaded someone's source code for a program and i needed to make some changes.

Now i want to compile it but it doesn't seem to work.

```
PROGS = isotociso
COMMON = tools.o bn.o ec.o  wiidisc.o rijndael.o
DEFINES = -DLARGE_FILES -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
LIBS = C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libwsock32.a C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libcrypto.a C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libcomdlg32.a

CC = gcc
#CFLAGS = -Wall -W -Os -Ilibwbfs -I.
CFLAGS = -Wall -m32 -W  -ggdb -Ilibwbfs -I.
LDFLAGS = -m32 -static

VPATH+=libwbfs
OBJS = $(patsubst %,%.o,$(PROGS)) $(COMMON)

all: $(PROGS)

$(PROGS): %: %.o $(COMMON) Makefile
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< $(COMMON) $(LIBS) -o $@

$(OBJS): %.o: %.c tools.h Makefile
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $@ 

clean:
 -rm -f $(OBJS) $(PROGS)
```

Output

```
C:\Users\Panda\Desktop\uloader_v4.1\src\isotociso\src>make
gcc -Wall -m32 -W  -ggdb -Ilibwbfs -I. -DLARGE_FILES -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c i
sotociso.c -o isotociso.o
process_begin: CreateProcess((null), gcc -Wall -m32 -W -ggdb -Ilibwbfs -I. -DLAR
GE_FILES -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c isotociso.c -o isotociso.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [isotociso.o] Error 2
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: Well.. Where is isotociso.c ?

Comment: That's not a reason for a CreateProcess error.

Comment: "make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified."

 I'm sorry, I thought I was reading the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me as if gcc is not in your PATH.

It also looks like you need [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) to get the libraries.

Comment: Where can i get C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libcrypto.a file? It's the only one missing

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in C(++) development under Windows, but my interpretation would be that it can't find the compiler itself. What development environment are you using?

Comment: Looks like im missing some files, i downloaded dev-cpp but im missing C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libwsock32.a C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libcrypto.a C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/libcomdlg32.a

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find a file. Are you sure you have all the required source files?

Comment: Yes i think so, isotociso.c is there so are other files like bn.c en.c rijndael.c tools.c

Comment: It's a CreateProcess error.  The command-line arguments are going to be irrelevant until gcc starts up, which means once the process is started.  The only thing I can think of that would stop CreateProcess is not finding gcc.